# How to switch dll creation from ANSI into UNICODE in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, plugins, encoding, visual-studio-2015, notepad++

I created a plugin for Notepad++ with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition using C#. It worked fine with Notepad++.

After a fresh re-installation of my Computer including Visual Studio and re-creating the dll, I get the error message from Notepad++ saying that "This ANSI plugin is not compatible wirh Unicode Notepad++".

It looks like Visual Studio is creating a dll in ANSI. Now the question is: How can I tell Visual Studio to create the dll with Unicode encoding?

Edit: The version from Notepad++ is in both cases the version 7.2.2 (32-bit). Because it is the same Notepad++ version I assume that the issue is more related to the creation of the dll in VS2015.

Comment: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development#Converting_plugins

Comment: In the past I did it without these steps. It just worked fine out of the box from VS2015

Comment: @stuartd That wiki page is over two years old. Unfortunately the wiki is not being updated and some of its contents is out of date.

Comment: @Guido Please [edit] the question to include the version numbers of the Notepad++ where the plugin worked and where it failed. There are a few different sets of support (or framework) code for writing plugins in C#, so also please include the version details of the plugin support code you used.

Comment: @AdrianHH: OK, question edited. It is the same version in both cases. Therefore I  assume that the issue is more likely related to the creation of the dll in VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. As I am using the NppPluginNET I also have to install th C++ package in VS2015. Now it works fine.
Thanks for your comments

Comment: I still struggle with compiling demo plugin with VS 2015 that will not complain about ANSI.  Can you give a few suggestions what to do?  What kind of package did you install?

Comment: @ChristopherB. Please install the C++ language support in the installation process